# Java error: constructor posts in class posts cannot be applied to given types

Tags: java

Hey im making an app with java but getting this error

```
constructor posts in class posts cannot be applied to given types;
                        posts post = new posts() ;
                                     ^
  required: String,String,String
  found: no arguments
```

in my file ManActivity.java i have

```
  jsonObject = response.getJSONObject(i);
                        posts post = new posts() ;

                        post.setTitle(jsonObject.getString("title"));
                        post.setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                        post.setCanonical_url(jsonObject.getString("Canonical_url"));
                        lstpost.add(post);
```

and in my posts.java file

```
public posts(String title, String description, String url) {
        this.title = title;
        this.description = description;
        this.canonical_url = url;
    }
```

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. You defined a constructor that takes three `String` arguments, but you provide none. I don't understand the confusion here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
required: String,String,String
found: no arguments
```

That's your error right there. You have a single constructor with 3 required arguments and you supplied none.

Try this instead:

```
posts post = new posts(jsonObject.getString("title"), jsonObject.getString("description"), jsonObject.getString("Canonical_url"));
```

---

Another solution would be to create an additional constructor which requires no arguments. It is fairly common to have multiple constructors.

```
public posts()
{
    //constructor body
}
```